# Scheduled delete logs from Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

How automatically remove logs that are older than one month from Azure Log Analytics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to automatically  remove logs that are older than one month, just set the log data retention period to `30` days.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/manage-cost-storage#change-the-data-retention-period